# Hello I have this same problem with my Flutter app where the YouTube API v3 doesn't load on Playstore and only on the Emulator

Tags: flutter, google-play, youtube-api, google-play-console, android-youtube-api

Hello I have this same problem with my Flutter app where the YouTube API  v3 doesn't load on Playstore and only on the Emulator ,

I tried to install Pro-Guard-rules and adjusted the build.gradle but nothing, Can anyone address the issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by opening the Android Manifest file and setting INTERNET Permissions to true, I cannot provide exact code at this moment, I am answering this on my phone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).